# Are linear combinations of eigenvectors also a eigenvector of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If $A$ is a square matrix, $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors of $A$, then $v + w$ is also an eigenvector of $A$.

Would this statement hold true? If not, could you give a counter example?

Comment: Try a simple $2\times2$ example with a diagonal matrix and see what you get.

Comment: Do they have the same eigenvalue?

Answer (score 2):

If $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue, then the sum $v+w$ is also an eigenvector. Otherwise it is false

For example, consider $A=\text{diag}\{1,2\}$, a $2 \times 2$ matrix. Then $(1,0)^t$ and $(0,1)^t$ are eigenvectors for the eigenvalues $1$ and $2$ respectively,but $(1,1)^t$  is not an eigenvector

Comment: what about in the case of identity matrix where a single eigenvalue has two eigenvectors

Comment: Every (non zero)vector is an eigenvector of $I$, since $Ix=x$, for all $x$

Answer (score 1):

No. Eigenvectors of matrix
\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}

are, for example $$\color{blue} {\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix}}
\text{, }\color{violet} {\begin{pmatrix} -1\\1\end{pmatrix}}$$

(because the transformation determined by this matrix don't change their direction)

but their sum

$$\color{blue} {\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix}} + \color{violet} {\begin{pmatrix} -1\\1\end{pmatrix}} = {\begin{pmatrix} 0\\2\end{pmatrix}}$$

not.

[image]